# Retrieve Dropbox Images in Website with png or jpg format

Tags: html, dropbox, dropbox-api

I have build a app. With that app i upload image to Dropbox. Each user has a Profil image save in Dropbox. I Save the Referenz in the Server to know which Image is for each user. Now i want to Display that image in my Website in Format png or jpg. I found a Dropbox api to Display image in Website but the give me the Image as blob format. The Image is rendering slow and it can not caching I'm Browser.

Somebody can help me to retrieve Dropbox Images in Website as a normal format (jpg,png,gif)

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it has explained completly here [Hosting images with Dropbox on your website](https://milanaryal.com/hosting-images-with-dropbox-on-your-website/)

Comment: Hey thanks for answer. I already read that blog before. My Use case is that when a user register, he upload a profile picture too. So I can not know before how is the name of the image. So I can not shared it in Dropbox since I don't know the name.  It must work automatically. My idea is to have a shared links for the folders where all my images are located. But so is don't work. It only works if I have a shared links for each image in my folder

Comment: There is a API to retrieve Dropbox images in website. But the retrieve all inages in my folder as blob. I hate blob format 

Comment: :D I don't think Dropbox allow you to do that

Comment: Why? So there is not a possibility to make that with Dropbox? I don't want to save my images in the database. So how can make that

Comment: I think because of policy stuff.I think https://imgbb.com/ can help you